# Does sampling error include measurement error?

Tags: sampling, standard-error, measurement-error

Gross sampling error (MSE) appears to be a composite of two errors sampling and measurement error. How do we assess measurement error ? can we find out net sampling error ?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea about "gross sampling error"? What is "MSE"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assuming by "gross sampling error" you mean mean-squared error or the $\epsilon$ term in a model like $Y=AX + \epsilon$

The error component of a model includes *all* sources of variability that are not explicitly included in the model. This includes sampling errors (uncertainty due to measuring only a subset of the population), measurement errors (uncertainty due to imprecisions in each measurement), and other things, like error attributable to a misspecified model (e.g., missing predictors/interactions).

Keep in mind that these are actually types of errors. For example, there may be measurement error associated with each variable in the model, and that error might be a combination of systematic error (essentially, a bias; e.g., someone forgot that the scale reports the weight of the container + its contents) and random error.  Given that, there isn't an automatic, all-purpose way of identifying the various error contributions.

One way to examine measurement errors is through **calibration**. For example, you could put a weight on the scale and compare the scale's reading to the known mass of the weight. In many cases, the phenomena causing measurement error are reasonably well understood and have a specific structure (e.g., [shot noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise)), which allows them to be incorporated into the model. Some large-scale physics experiments take this to incredible extremes to compare an apparatus's expected performance to the real data. Surveys are sometimes **benchmarked** by comparing data collected during the survey to larger data sets. For example, you might ask participants for demographic information (e.g., age, gender, income). These values are then compared to known population values (e.g., from a census or tax records), which might tell you how representative your respondents are of the general population.

Sampling error is much harder to measure directly. You might expect sampling error to shrink as the number of samples approaches the size of the population, whereas a systematic measurement error would remain approximately the same, regardless of sample size.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, the literature suggests that measurement error does not influence variance though constant bias (construct bias) here may have a bearing on the estimate of mean effect-size. These ideas are very explicit to me, Please elaborate for me in the context of meta-analysis of sample correlations

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In reality, measurement error can take many different forms, but it's often **modelled** as a random effect coming from an $N(0, \epsilon)$ distribution. If that assumption is true, then the measurement error won't affect the mean (it's zero-mean), but will increase the variance. Since correlations are scaled by the (product of the) variances, it will bias them downwards. Its affect on regression depends on where it is in the model. Maybe this will help: http://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats2/l21.pdf

Comment: A re-look suggests that the answer is good and the comment suggests correctly the effect on mean. However, in the case of variance also, being a random effect, it should not affect the variance. In general, the answer is accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the checkmark! However, I disagree that measurement error does not affect the variance. 

Suppose the "true" data are distributed normally with some mean and variance: $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and contaminated with (additive) normally-distributed measurement error $N(0, \epsilon)$. Then, your observations will be from another normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2 + \epsilon)$. Both $\sigma^2$ and $\epsilon$ have to be positive, so the variance is therefore biased upwards.

Comment: Variance is computed as sum of squared deviations from the mean. If we have a random variable, the deviations part of values indicates "gross sampling error" which includes measurement error. The latter part once again is distributed as a randomly distributed variable. The measurement error thus affects individual variances of values randomly implying that (overall) there is a zero effect on average variance for the dataset. If we have a constant bias (scale error), it will influence mean estimate. Once again, it will not affect the overall (average)variance.